# Add one to INT in table if not exists issue

Tags: php, mysql

(this is my first question so sorry if I do something wrong)

So I am trying to write a tournament standings program. The idea is submit 12 players through a form with their placement and then if that person is *not* already in the table, create a row in a DB and if it *is* in the table, add one to the appropriate column. Here is the applicable code :

```
        for($i = 1; $i < 14; $i++) {
        $g = $i - 1;
        $fields = array('first', 'second', 'third', 'fourth', 'lose', 'tie');
        $array[$g] = array($_GET['nameplayer' . $i], $_GET['placementplayer' . $i]); //Because there are 12 people, I used a for-loop for selecting player # hence the $array[$g]. It is  being filled with the name and placement

        //Insert Player Name
        if($array[$g][0] != "") {
            $k = $array[$g][0]; //Name of the person
            $z = $_GET['tournyname'];
            $t = $array[$g][1]; //Placement of the person (can be 1, 2, 3, 4, tie or lose)

        $checkme = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tournamentstandings WHERE name = '$k' AND tournyname = '$_GET[tournyname]'")or die(mysql_error()); //Getting the specific row for the guy I wanna add +1 to

        if($t != "Tie" && $t != "Loss") { //Defining $y which is the field name for where the +1 should go
            $y = $fields[$t - 1];
        } else if ($t == "Tie") {
            $y = $fields[5];
        } else if ($t == "Loss") {
            $y = $fields[4];
        }

            if (mysql_num_rows($checkme)){
                $qone = mysql_query("SELECT $y FROM tournamentstandings WHERE name = '$k' AND tournyname = '$_GET[tournyname]'");
                    while($query = mysql_fetch_array($qone)) {
                        echo "updated";
                        mysql_query("UPDATE tournamentstandings SET $y = '$qone[$y] + 1' WHERE name = '$k' AND tournyname = '$z'") or die(mysql_error()); //THIS IS THE TROUBLE LINE
                    }
            }
            else if($y == "first" && !mysql_num_rows($checkme)) {
                mysql_query("REPLACE INTO tournamentstandings(name, first, tie, second, third, fourth, lose, tournyname, totalplayed, totalpoints, pointspergame, winpercentage) VALUES('$k', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '$z', '0', '0', '0', '0')")or die(mysql_error()); //Does the exact same thing but for $y == "second" and so on inserting 1 if the row does not already exist
            }
```

So the issue is that sometimes when I add a new player, it goes to like 3 instead of 1 meaning that  the 'trouble line' is called but no "update" (echoed) is displayed which is bizarre. If I comment out that line, it works fine but will not add +1 if the row already exists

So table wise lets say someone submits 12 names; name1 (first), name2 (second), name3 (third), name4 (fourth), name5 (lose) ... name 12 (lose) and none of those exist all under tournyname FFA (can be FFA, 1 Ally, 2 Ally, 6v6 which you can specify in the form)

it should be :

```
name | first     | tie     | second     | third     | fourth     | lose     | tournyname
name1|  1        |  0      |  0         |   0       |   0        |  0       |     FFA
name2|  0        |  0      |  1         |   0       |   0        |  0       |     FFA
name3|  0        |  0      |  0         |   1       |   0        |  0       |     FFA
name4|  0        |  0      |  0         |   0       |   1        |  0       |     FFA
name5|  0        |  0      |  0         |   0       |   0        |  1       |     FFA
```

and so on

but what is happening is:

```
name | first     | tie     | second     | third     | fourth     | lose     | tournyname
name1|  3        |  0      |  0         |   0       |   0        |  0       |     FFA
name2|  0        |  0      |  3         |   0       |   0        |  0       |     FFA
name3|  0        |  0      |  0         |   2       |   0        |  0       |     FFA
name4|  0        |  0      |  0         |   0       |   1        |  0       |     FFA
name5|  0        |  0      |  0         |   0       |   0        |  1       |     FFA
```

Or something random like that where the first 3 are broken and the last few are okay. When I try to update it later (just add one to an existing row, it works fine. It is just that initial submission. I have tried a while to figure out what it is and I dont know. I have tried :

1. Changing queries using REPLACE
2. Limiting the number of times the for loop runs to the number of submitted entries (does not have to be 12, can be 1-12
3. Adding AUTO_INCREMENT id
4. Primary Key changes

and a whole bunch of playing around with the select queries and such. Is there something small I am missing? :) If I am missing something that yall need just let me know!

Thanks very much!

INSERTED IMAGE OF ISSUE ::

[image: should not be 3 or 2! should be 1!]

All of the red boxes indicate the THIRD BATCH OF 12 all of the black boxes indicated the errors. Those numbers should be one because before I submitted the form, those rows did not exist. All of the names are unique so nothing in that pic should be above a one.

Comment: What do "first", "second", "third", "fourth", "lose", and "tie" mean? What is this a tournament of? Are these races with all people competing? Are individual games played between two of the people?

Comment: So in the form, there is <select> with <option>first</option> second.. and so on. The idea is to add one to the old number in the column based on what they submited with the <select>. They are placements in a game, first place second so on.. It is just an ongoing tournament of a Warcraft III game  not exactly races. Each game consists of 12 people.

Comment: WO I think I figured it out. I changed the form action from its own page to a different PHP page with the queries. To clear some stuff up. amar: Not sure how real data would have helped anything @shubhansh: TYvm your method worked. I am not sure how to +rep cause I think that is what yall do here. Do I just upvote the answer? :) all: Tyvm for your responses! BTW That was the end of that statement. Forgot to put in the closing brackets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [**insert...on duplicate key update**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) in place of first searching for value and then updating the value. It will reduce MySQL operation to single query and must solve your problem as well.

Comment: Hey so I tried
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO tournamentstandings(name, first, tie, second, third, fourth, lose, tournyname, totalplayed, totalpoints, pointspergame, winpercentage) VALUES('$k', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '$z', '0', '0', '0', '0') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE $y = '$val + 1'")or die(mysql_error());                         Where I would get the $val var if the row exists already but it also did not add one to the existing row :(.

Comment: $y should contain the column name to be updated and should be properly escaped. $val should be initial value which i guess will be same as $y. For finding columns to be updated you can use if else or switch-case and set $y with suitable value.

Comment: Tyvm your answer works :) I cannot upvote cause I dont have 15 rep but when I get that ill upvote ya ! :)

Comment: Good to listen that it was useful. Since its your question, you can accept the answer by clicking on tick mark on left side of answer.

Answer (score 0):

It might simplify your life if you pushed the SQL calls to stored procs in the database, then you can test the SQL separately from the application code.

Comment: Hey that sounds like a good idea but I am not sure the difference between that and what I am doing now other than simplification. But when I get home from school I will definently try that and get back to you.

Answer (score 0):

```
while($query = mysql_fetch_array($qone)) {
    echo "updated";
    $val=$query["$y"]+1;
    mysql_query("UPDATE tournamentstandings SET $y = '$val' WHERE name = '$k' AND tournyname = '$z'") or die(mysql_error()); //THIS IS THE TROUBLE LINE
                    }
```

Comment: Sadly that did not seem to work. I tried it before though and I just tried it again. It echos "updated" 12 times like it should but does not actually update (I kept the $qone query) but it did not update at all from 1, just created the row and then stopped.

Comment: It should be `$query["$y"]` not `$qone["$y"]`. i edited the answer

Comment: still havin issues. the first two sets of 12 people that I add, it will add correctly (create a new row with one in the appropriate col) but the third one and so on, it is really bizarre. Adds like 3's 2's and 1's randomly. Like I say if I comment the update query out, it works perfectly (but will not +1 if row exists) but if not commented it breaks. What is the strangest is that before the update  query I have an echo "updated"; but nothing is echoed when it adds like 3 to the score. If you would like I can show you.

Comment: (inserted image of the issue)

Comment: I think this image can not help us anymore...try to trace your program with real data.by the way, i could not see, where did you close your `for` loop and first `if` statement.